# Why a file generated with sudo is not owned by root?

Tags: command-line, permissions, root

I run the following command in a terminal.

```
sudo tcpdump -c 2 -w /tmp/z.pcap icmp
```

Then run the following command in a terminal.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

The file generated belongs to the user tcpdump instead of root.

```
$ stat /tmp/z.pcap 
  File: /tmp/z.pcap
  Size: 158             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 4068722     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  115/ tcpdump)   Gid: (  120/ tcpdump)
Access: 2021-02-25 10:05:52.910772287 -0500
Modify: 2021-02-25 10:06:00.102859691 -0500
Change: 2021-02-25 10:06:00.102859691 -0500
 Birth: 2021-02-25 10:05:52.910772287 -0500
```

The command tcpdump belongs to the root. Why the file generated does not belong to the root?

```
$ ls -l $(which tcpdump)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1261512 2021/01/15-17:41:47 /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

Answer (score 6):

See `man tcpdump`. It's generally good practice to NOT run as root if it's not necessary, so the developers added:

> ```
>   -Z user
>   --relinquish-privileges=user
>          If  tcpdump is running as root, after opening the capture device
>          or input savefile, change the user ID to user and the  group  ID
>          to the primary group of user.
>
>          This  behavior  is  enabled  by default (-Z tcpdump), and can be
>          disabled by -Z root.
> ```

In other words: tcpdump, once spawned, does not need to keep root permissions, so it sheds them.

Comment: +1 I just searched through the man-page to find exactly this ;-)

Comment: @pLumo feel free to steal anything you like for your answer, which will make it more complete. I've never been a fan of part-of-this-answer and part-of-that-answer to get a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because `tcpdump` will will spawn a subprocess that is owned by `tcpdump`:

```
$ ps auf | grep [t]cpdump
root       47749  0.0  0.0  16432  7264 pts/1    S+   16:16   0:00  \_ sudo tcpdump -c 2 -w /tmp/z.pcap icmp
tcpdump    47750  0.0  0.0  11084  6252 pts/1    S+   16:16   0:00      \_ tcpdump -c 2 -w /tmp/z.pcap icmp
```

It drops privileges as it doesn't need it anymore. Use `-Z` option to change that behavior. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1319296/631600) for details.